# Show days enjoyed sql

Tags: sql

My query is that I have two tables, one called `sec_users` with the following fields:

```
pk_user, name, days_available
```

And another call `solicitud` with the following fields:

```
pk_solicitud, fk_empleado, n_dias
```

Where `fk_empleado` of the table `solicitud` is the `pk_user` foreign key of the `sec_users` table

Well, I have a small report where it shows me the free days that are left to each user but I also want to show you and with the same query the days that that user has requested

For example, user1, who has 24 days off, creates an application and asks for 4 rest days and another 10 days. I want you to show me in addition to the remaining days that are 24-4-10 = 14 days off, you have to show me the days that you have already used: 24-14 = 10 days consumed. I have the following code but it gives me numbers that I do not want:

```
SELECT u.pk_user, u.dias_disponibles - sum(s.n_diassolicitados) AS dias_libres, (SELECT SUM(N_DIASSOLICITADOS) as dias_disfrutados FROM solicitud)
FROM sec_users u, solicitud s
WHERE s.fk_empleado = u.pk_user
GROUP BY u.pk_user
```

This function shows me this:

```
Usuario             dias_libres   dias_disfrutados
==============    ==============  ==============
Usuario 1                10              79
```

You must show me this:

```
Usuario             Dias libres   Dias disfrutados
==============    ==============  ==============
Usuario 1                10              14
```

Nose because it does not show.

Comment: Remember Tip 1 from your previous question?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you want:

```
SELECT u.pk_user,
       (u.dias_disponibles - COALESCE(dias_disfrutados, 0)) AS dias_libres,
       COALESCE(dias_disfrutados, 0)
FROM (SELECT u.*,
             (SELECT SUM(N_DIASSOLICITADOS)
              FROM solicitud s
              WHERE s.fk_empleado = u.pk_user
             ) as dias_disfrutados
      FROM sec_users u 
     ) u;
```

Notes:

- *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.
- You don't appear to need the outer aggregation.
- Calculate the value that you need once, and then use it where you need it.

Comment: This function is fine, but if I create a new user and that user does not create any request, that user's fields appear as NULL

Comment: @AlvaroRomanFranco . . . That is easily fixed using `COALESCE()`.

Comment: THANK YOU! IT HAS BEEN A GREAT HELP

Answer (score 1):

```
You have not filtered by user, this is how you need it:

SELECT u.pk_user, 
       u.dias_disponibles - sum(s.n_diassolicitados) AS dias_libres, 
       (SELECT SUM(N_DIASSOLICITADOS) as dias_disfrutados 
        FROM solicitud s2
        WHERE s2.fk_empleado = u.pk_user)
FROM sec_users u

join solicitud s
ON s.fk_empleado = u.pk_user

GROUP BY u.pk_user
```

However, this is not a quality code. Better to just include it as this:

```
 SELECT u.pk_user, 
       u.dias_disponibles - sum(s.n_diassolicitados) AS dias_libres, 
       SUM(N_DIASSOLICITADOS) as dias_disfrutados
    FROM sec_users u

    join solicitud s
    ON s.fk_empleado = u.pk_user

    GROUP BY u.pk_user
```

Comment: This function is what I was looking for, but if I create a new user and that user does not create any request, that user does not appear

Comment: Then use LEFT JOIN instead of just JOIN. Simple JOIN defaults to INNER JOIN, which ignores missing combinations.

Comment: Even if I use LEFT JOIN or INNER JOIN, that user still does not appear, since I have not created any request and I want it to appear

Comment: Use the second query. Use Left join instead of join. It should appear if it exists in sec_users table.

Comment: THANK YOU! IT HAS BEEN A GREAT HELP