# Do not add extra days

Tags: mysql, sql

Good! I have this function:

```
SELECT u.name, (u.dias_disponibles + COALESCE(dias_extra,0)) as dias_disponibles,
       (u.dias_disponibles - COALESCE(dias_disfrutados,0)) AS dias_libres,
       COALESCE(dias_disfrutados,0) as dias_disfrutados
FROM (

     select u.name, u.dias_disponibles
          , sum( case when s.fk_motivo = 1
                        OR s.fk_motivo = 3) 
                then  dias_disfrutados else 0 end ) as dias_disfrutados
          , sum( case when  FK_MOTIVO = 4
                then dias_disfrutados else 0 end )  as dias_baja
          , sum( case when  FK_MOTIVO = 2
                then dias_disfrutados else 0 end )  as dias_extra

      FROM sec_users u 
      left join solicitud s on s.fk_empleado = u.pk_user
      group by u.name ) u
```

I have two tables:

```
sec_users:

pk_user   name    dias_disponibles
========  =====   ==================
1         Usuario         24

solicitud:

pk_solicitud    fk_empleado    dias_disfrutados    motivo
============    ============   =================  ==========
1                    1                 10            1
```

Well, this function creates a small report, my problem is that as you see at the beginning `dias_extra` it adds up to `dias_disponibles`, that does it well. The problem is that it does not change the `dias_libres` or `dias_disfrutados`. What am I missing?

For example: A user has 24 `dias_disponibles` and asks for 10 `dias_disfrutados`. The result will be 24-10 = 14 `dias_libres`.

If the user requests 1 `dias_extra`, this day must be added to `dias_disponibles`:

24 + 1 = 25

And in this case you must also modify `dias_libres` and `dias_disfrutados` but it does not.

When the user requests `10 dias_disfrutados`:

```
name    dias_disponibles   dias_libres    dias_disfrutados
======  ================   ============   ================
Usuario      24                 14               10
```

When the user requests an `dias_extra`

```
name    dias_disponibles   dias_libres    dias_disfrutados
======  ================   ============   ================
Usuario      25                 15               10
```

The latter does not

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: It is already edited

Comment: Why do you keep asking questions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49047630/sentence-in-a-single-select), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48991803/subtract-two-fields-from-different-tables), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49006423/query-sql-to-subtract-two-fields), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49008675/show-days-enjoyed-sql)) about the same query under different SO accounts ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9390912/alvaro-roman-franco), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9379530/alvaro-roman), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9433247/xerox))?

Comment: @HoneyBadger It is not the same, can you give me an answer to what I ask?

Comment: @Xerox, I don't have an answer, because, even after multiple requests, I still haven't seen any sample data.

Comment: @HoneyBadger I have edited the question and added the sample data that I want to appear

Comment: Yes, you've shown the expected output, but **not** the data you are selecting from.

Comment: @HoneyBadger The data is already in the question

Comment: @HoneyBadger To see each `solicitud` has a reason, that the reasons can be: `1 = Vacaciones or 2 = Dias extra`

Comment: Your sample is far from complete, what is `FK_MOTIVO`, what is `N_DIASSOLICITADOS`, what is `fk_estado`? Please re-read [mcve]. To you this may seem all logical, but we don't know anything about your database or the data it contains. One data record per table is **not enough**. This is no doubt also the reason you have to ask 5 questions to get this report right. Give us data, and you'll get a better answer.

Comment: @HoneyBadger Look at this link and you will understand what I want better. I have put a sentence that makes me the report well but when I execute it: select dias_disponibles
  from sec_users
  where name = 'Alvaro'

I keep coming out 24 days